# C# strings not visible

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'll try to make it the most clear as I can. I am doing an form inserting data to SQLite

```
 public partial class Register : Form
{
    private SQLiteConnection sql_con;
    private SQLiteCommand sql_cmd;
    private SQLiteDataAdapter DB;
    private DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    private DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    public Register()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = textBox1.Text;
        string lastname = textBox2.Text;
        string login = textBox3.Text;
        string password = textBox4.Text;
        string mail = textBox5.Text;
```

then it does some md5 hash calculations concerning login and pass inserting it to DB. After that I want to insert the rest of string via

```
public void WstawReszte(string name, string lastname, string mail, string phone)
        {
            name = textBox1.Text;

   string  query = string.Format("INSERT INTO USERS (NAME,LASTNAME,PHONE,MAIL) values ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3})", name, lastname, mail, phone);
   SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, sql_con);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

However it inserts nothing except hashes, and VisualStudio is still telling me that strings name etc. are not used. What can be the problem?

Summarizing:
via Button1 I want to insert login and pass in form of MD5 and rest of information to DB, but only login and pass are inserted

Comment: Your query is missing a single quote after '{3}.  Is it missing in your code?

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) is going to *wreak* your program.

Comment: Yep thanks for noticing but that does not cause the problem, 0,1,2 should be inserted correctly. After correcting same issue.

Comment: I don't know what you are going to use it for but watch out for sql injections.  The way you have it set up you are opening yourself up to working weekends and nights to recover the data.

Comment: You are also overwriting the value of `name` in `WstawReszte`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @Servy I assume it's about SQL Injection :) However I am doing it for education purposes, after I'll be able to insert data anyhow I'll do it fine :)

Comment: @D Stanley I guess not intentionally ...

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're actually calling WstawReszte?  (Is that in `button1_Click`?)

Comment: Calling WstawReszte is in button1_Click too

Comment: Oh duh, I'm finally getting what you're doing.  You're inserting login and password via a completely different command that you haven't shown, right?  Then you're trying to insert the rest of the fields for that record in the code you've shown.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yep, that can be true :) MD5 via similar as here http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So WstawReszte is either not getting called or is failing silently (maybe because of a try-catch that's not shown?)

Comment: @PawełGranat If you're doing this for educational purpose then you should educate yourself on how to solve this problem *properly*, and get into the habit of writing safe, effective, working code whenever you write code.  If your learning process teaches you to write code that you later need to unlearn and avoid doing in the future, then it is doing more harm than good.  The negative consequences of leaving SQL injection vulnerabilities in programs like this is very real, and significant.  Now is not at all too early to start learning how to avoid doing it.

Comment: No try-catch present so I guess it's not called

Comment: Well, if it's not getting called, that would explain why Visual Studio says the various variables aren't being used in `button1_Click`.  In any case, the insert in `WstawReszte` would probably fail anyway if you have your database set up to require non-null for the user and password fields.  You probably want an UPDATE statement rather than an INSERT.